# Show most popular post of last 12 months

Tags: wp-query, popular-posts

I use the Ribbon theme that has a nice tabbed widget showing the most popular and most recent posts. I would like to limit the most popular posts to the last 12 months. I would rather not use a plugin for that but change the code in the theme file. The query is like so:

```
function mts_popular_tabs( $posts = 5 ) {
    $popular = new WP_Query('showposts='. $posts .'&orderby=comment_count&order=desc');
    $popular_post_num = 1;
    while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post();
```

I tried this snippet:

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-365 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

It works for the widget but effects other queries, too. I tried to remove the filter, but it didn't work:

```
wp_reset_query();
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

I tried to rewrite the query like so with no luck:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$todayminusone = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year'));
$args = array(  
    'date_query' => array(  
        array(  
            'after' => $today,  
            'before' => $todayminusone,  
        ),  
    ),  
    'showposts' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'order' => 'desc'  
); 

function mts_popular_tabs() {
    $popular = new WP_Query($args);
    $popular_post_num = 1;
    while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post();
```

I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for the help. This is the code I use now:

```
function mts_popular_tabs( $nr = 5 )
{
    $args = array(  
        'date_query'     => array( array( 'after' => '-1 year' ) ),  
        'posts_per_page' => (int) $nr,
        'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
        'order'          => 'DESC'  
    ); 
    $popular = new WP_Query( $args );
    $popular_post_num = 1;
while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post();
    ...
```

Comment: You seem to be on right track in latter attempt, but you need to be declaring arguments _inside_ the function, not outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Of course, I have to declare the arguments inside the function. How dumb of me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @Rarst suggested, you must have your `$args` defined within your function. You could solve it by using *global variables*, but we **don't want** too many such variables flying around!

Check out the PHP docs on [the scope of a variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) or write your code in a [class](http://php.net/language.oop5.php).

You can also simplify your query. Here's an example how your function could look like:

```
function mts_popular_tabs( $nr = 5 )
{
    $args = array(  
        'date_query'     => array( array( 'after' => '-1 year' ) ),  
        'posts_per_page' => (int) $nr,
        'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
        'order'          => 'DESC'  
    ); 
    $popular = new WP_Query( $args );
    // ... your loop ...
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This will generate the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
    FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE 1=1 
          AND ( ( post_date > '2013-04-06 11:30:26' ) ) 
          AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
          AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
    ORDER BY wp_posts.comment_count DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 5
```

if the current date is `'2014-04-06 11:30:26'`.

*ps:* If you want the `posts_where` filter to only affect your instance of `WP_Query`, you should also move it into the function:

```
function mts_popular_tabs( $nr = 5 )
{
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    $popular = new WP_Query( $args );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    // ... your loop ...
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

but you don't need it in this case.

Hope this helps.